# Selecting the stream type for Android Camera2 or CameraX

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, android-camerax

I need to programmaticaly read pixel values from the camera stream identified by `CAM_STREAM_TYPE_PREVIEW` stream type.

In CameraX API, this stream is exposed via `androidx.camera.core.Preview` interface.  However, I need programmatic access to the pixels of this stream.  In other words, I need it in a way `androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis` exposes its stream.

Is there a setting that would allow me to do that?

Comment: What's wrong with ImageAnalysis?

Comment: `ImageAnalysis` reads `CAM_STREAM_TYPE_ANALYSIS`, which *on my device* is a different stream containing a different image.  This is not a normal, off-the-shelf device, and this is not something regular consumer would encounter

Comment: This probably means that you cannot use the CameraX API for your purposes ☹️